# Wicket. execute javascript before AjaxLink hangler

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal-dialog, wicket

There is Wicket AjaxLink, which when clicked calls the standard handler (this opens the modal window)
How to insert JavaScript code that will be executed after clicking on the link before the standard handler to check the series of conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use class AjaxCallListener. This class has a number of methods returning the JavaScript code that is executed during the lifecycle of an AJAX request, including preconditions. AjaxCallListener must be used overriding AjaxLink#updateAjaxAttributes. See [user guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_creating_custom_ajax_call_listener) for an introduction to this topic.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer helped in solving the problem. I've added AjaxCallListener into AjaxRequestAttributes and overrode  getBeforeHandler. )))

Comment: there's also gePreconditon you can use for your task.